# Is it possible to lay out a table with 2 columns. The first column with many td's, the second one with one?

Tags: html

Is it possible to lay out a table with 2 columns. The first column with many td's, the second one with only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes use rowspan or colspan to merge td. Example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this produce a bar on top with three <td>'s, and then below that a single bar across? I'm looking for the perpindicular direction of this. In which you would have a column going up and down with many objects in it. And then next to it, a single item.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use [colspan](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html)...or you might want rowspan (colspan's opposite :))

Directly from the article (with enclosing the attributes in quotes:

```
<TABLE BORDER="2" CELLPADDING="4">
<TR> <TH COLSPAN="2">Production</TH> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Raha Mutisya</TD>      <TD>1493</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Shalom Buraka</TD>     <TD>3829</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Brandy Davis</TD>      <TD>0283</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TH COLSPAN="2">Sales</TH> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Claire Horne</TD>      <TD>4827</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Bruce Eckel</TD>       <TD>7246</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Danny Zeman</TD>       <TD>5689</TD> </TR>
</TABLE>
```

[Here is the W3 article](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html)

Comment: please avoid using uppercase tag and use quote for attribute value

Comment: @JeromeC. This was just a cut and paste. I agree with the attributes, but I dont know that it matters on the caps. If you look at the direct from w3 article, they use caps. I agree it looks better with lowercase, but I dont think that is a must

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking you know that (a 7k+ reputation just generally knows that). But I don't like to see it because full of examples on the web continue to use caps, which can be confusing for beginners ;)

Comment: Wouldn't this produce a bar on top with three <td>'s, and then below that a single bar across? I'm looking for the perpindicular direction of this. In which you would have a column going up and down with many objects in it. And then next to it, a single item.